# Read content of maven repository

Tags: java, maven

I'm trying to read the names of the of the artifacts in a given directory of a maven repository.

[image: Repository]

I want to know how to read the names example ... abbot , aceqisecurity, activiation .. etc

I'm not sure which library to use or how to read the names? Any help would be appreciated!

Edit:

I've actually noticed that I phrased the question wrong! When i'm asking how to read the names I mean how can I read the names by putting the library/artifact name in a list/array. So I'm not sure what libraries to use to actually read the repository. Hopefully I clarified.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want. You might want to go to the pom.xml level in the directory structure and the names are in the `xml`s. Or do you want to write a Java code?

Comment: I want to be able to get the names of all the content in a directory and put it into a list so that I would display it in a dropdown menu for a webapp.

Comment: Is this a local repository or a web based? In the 1st case, you can find all the `pom.xml`s and find the names in them.

Comment: Its a web based repository.

Comment: A repository is just a bunch of files available over HTTP. Apply web scraping to get to all the POMs. (I.e. Apache HttpComponents and NekoHtml.) Then just parse the POMs for the `groupId` and `artifactId`

Comment: @millimoose might be right... I don't think there is a "Java Maven Client for Web Based Repositories".

Comment: See also the docs of the 2.x repo layout: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVEN/Repository+Layout+-+Final

Answer (score 1):

A Maven repository usually contains Java libraries (called *artifacts* by Maven).
Artifacts are ordered by groupId, artifactId and by version.

`groupId` is similar to the package name and is often starting with *com*, *org* or *net* like hostnames. The groupId is separated by dots. Each part will by mapped by a folder.

`artifactId` is a the name of the library. A folder is created for it.

`version` is the version number of the library. Same here, each version of a library has its own folder.

Let's take an example with the library commons-email 1.3.1 from Apache Commons.
The groupId is `org.apache.commons`, the artifactId is `commons-email` and the version is `1.3.1`.

So for this library, inside a Maven repository you will find:

```
org
 |- apache
     |- commons
         |- commons-email
             |- 1.3.1
                 |- commons-email-1.3.1.jar
                 |- commons-email-1.3.1.jar.asc
                 |- commons-email-1.3.1.pom
                 |- commons-email-1.3.1.pom.asc
```

Based on this, you can see that *abbot*, *acegisecurity* and *activation* are the start (or the whole part) of the `groupId` of one or more libraries.

You can browse Maven central repository here :
http://search.maven.org/#browse

Answer (score 0):

In Maven you can identify any library by three identifiers: `groupId`, `artifactId` and `version`. Based on these name you find the library at this location: `/mavenRepo/groupId/artifactId/version/groupId-version.jar` . A mention with the names that have '.' in groupId is that they are considered in different directories.

Let's take an example:

```
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
<version>3.2.2.RELEASE</version>
```

This dependency would be saved at the following path: `maven-local-repo/org/springframework/spring-orm/3.2.2.RELEASE/spring-orm-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar`.